# Limiting problematic font mapping in Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I am using Ghostscript to process some PDFs for the size reduction.  Sometimes the fonts embedded when processed are inferior to the local fonts used when viewing the original.

A few questions:

1. I imagine that fonts which are already embedded in an input PDF are reused in the output PDF rather than sourced from the local machine.  Is this correct? Is this true even when subsetting is enabled?
2. Is it possible (and reasonably) to have Ghostscript only embed a missing font when it has a strict match?
3. Is it possible for Ghostscript to retain fonts already embedded in the input PDF but not bother embedding fonts that are missing in the source?

## Background

Currently I am using the following command with Ghostscript 9.23:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
   -dDownsampleColorImages=true \
   -dDownsampleGrayImages=true \
   -dDownsampleMonoImages=true \
   -dColorImageResolution=72 \
   -dGrayImageResolution=72 \
   -dMonoImageResolution=72 \
   -dColorImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0 \
   -dGrayImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0 \
   -dMonoImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0 \
   -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dPARANOIDSAFER -dBATCH \
   -dDetectDuplicateImages=true \
   -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

However, in some cases the font remapping appears to be hurting the rendered result.  Here is a case where a source PDF without any embedded fonts suffered some rendering degradation for the typical viewer after font substitution and embedding:

Before:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
FrizQuadrata-Bold                    Type 1            MacRoman         no  no  no       7  0
Helvetica-Black                      Type 1            MacRoman         no  no  no       9  0
Helvetica-Light                      Type 1            MacRoman         no  no  no      59  0
Helvetica-Bold                       TrueType          MacRoman         no  no  no      65  0
Helvetica-Bold                       Type 1            MacRoman         no  no  no      68  0
ZapfDingbats                         Type 1            Custom           no  no  no      70  0
Helvetica-Black                      Type 1            MacRoman         no  no  no     108  0
Helvetica-BlackOblique               Type 1            MacRoman         no  no  no     136  0
ZapfDingbats                         Type 1            Custom           no  no  no     137  0
Helvetica-Bold                       Type 1            MacRoman         no  no  no     780  0
Helvetica-LightOblique               Type 1            MacRoman         no  no  no     926  0
```

After:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
VRGBBC+Times-Bold                    Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no       8  0
JTHLZY+Helvetica-Bold                Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no      10  0
ETQHWQ+Helvetica                     Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no      20  0
ZapfDingbats                         Type 1            ZapfDingbats     no  no  yes     29  0
LSUJJC+Helvetica-BoldOblique         Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no      46  0
RBDUAX+Helvetica-Oblique             Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no     202  0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot to answer here......

> ```
> I imagine that fonts which are already embedded in an input PDF are reused in the output PDF rather than sourced from the local
> ```
>
> machine. Is this correct? Is this true even when subsetting is
>   enabled?

When you create a new PDF file, Ghostscript's pdfwrite device will, by default, preserve everything it possibly can from the input. This is actually vitally important for fonts.

> ```
> Is it possible (and reasonably) to have Ghostscript only embed a missing font when it has a strict match?
> ```

And how do you define a 'strict match' ?

> ```
> Is it possible for Ghostscript to retain fonts already embedded in the input PDF but not bother embedding fonts that are missing in the
> ```
>
> source?

You can certainly adjust the way Ghostscript's pdfwrite device embeds fonts, there are several controls, all documented. The AlwaysEmbed, NeverEmbed arrays permit you to prevent certain named fonts being embedded, there's also EmbedAlllFonts and SubsetFonts.

Try setting EmbedAllFonts to false (**important** also set SubsetFonts to false) with your test document. I'd also suggest that you share a PDF file which exhibits the problems because its hard to see why there would be a problem. 'some degradation' doesn't really tell me very much. The fonts being embedded (with the exceptions of FrizQuadrata, Helvetica-Black, Helvetica-BlackOblique and Helvetica-LightOblique) are part of the base 13 and so should be fine.

Its a bad idea to **not** embed fonts (apart from the base 13) in a PDF file, its supposed to be portable, and if you rely on font substitution you always run the risk of the rendered result being incorrect.

Presumably you actually have these fonts locally, so why not just make them available to Ghostscript so that the pdfwrite device can embed subsets of the font in the new PDF file ? Then it will be portable.